# Sectioning and Chaptering in AMSart not working at all w/example

Tags: sectioning, chapters, amsart

I am wondering why AMSart which reputedly supports sectioning and chaptering doesn't compile my chapter headings at all. I have a non-working example here which shows that neither the section nor the chapter command works. Can someone help figure out how to put chapters and sections in there? Thank you so much!

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}            %You need this
%\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}              %Puts authors' affiliations below names
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %More math symbols
\usepackage{mathtools}                      %More math symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       %Insert pictures
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}    %Lets you use math
\usepackage{tikz}                           %Graphs
\usepackage{setspace}                       %Allows margin and text spacing options
\usepackage{xcolor}                         %Color
\usepackage{pdfpages}                       %Lets you append pdfs
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}                   %For the bibliography
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}                 %Punctuation in bibliography
\usepackage{datenumber}                     %More formatting options for date
%\usepackage[implicit=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}                            %Lets you link items
\usepackage{tabularx}                       %Prettier tables, if we're doing them in LaTeX
\usepackage{xcolor}                         %Colors
\usepackage{needspace}                      %Insert pagebreak if not enough space
%
%Old ones
%\documentclass[a4paper,aps,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox} %To generate the bibliography in aps, we need this.
\usepackage{rotating} %To use with the enviroments begin sideways etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %To prevent unexpected results when this text is copied.
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} %Das ist kein Zeichenprogramm.
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage[citecolor= black,colorlinks=true,linkcolor = black,urlcolor  = black]{hyperref} 
%\usepackage{hypernat} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace} %This allows spacing
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry} %The geometry package allows the adjustment of the margin.
\usepackage{titlesec} %This is for the spacing of section titles.
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%End of packages and libraries.
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\@ifundefined{textcolor}{}
{%
 \definecolor{BLACK}{gray}{0}
 \definecolor{WHITE}{gray}{1}
 \definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}
 \definecolor{GREEN}{rgb}{0,1,0}
 \definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1}
 \definecolor{CYAN}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
 \definecolor{MAGENTA}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
 \definecolor{YELLOW}{cmyk}{0,0,1,0}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

% latex advancedlab ; dvips -Ppdf -t letter -G0 advancedlab

%%%New commands
\newcommand{\?}{'\-\nobreak\hspace{0pt}} %This introduces a nifty apostrophe
\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vectbr}{vecb_{r}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\col}{col}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\newcommand{\distas}[1]{\mathbin{\overset{#1}{\kern\z@\sim}}}%
\newsavebox{\mybox}\newsavebox{\mysim}
\newcommand{\distras}[1]{%
  \savebox{\mybox}{\hbox{\kern3pt$\scriptstyle#1$\kern3pt}}%
  \savebox{\mysim}{\hbox{$\sim$}}%
  \mathbin{\overset{#1}{\kern\z@\resizebox{\wd\mybox}{\ht\mysim}{$\sim$}}}%
}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%Commands for layout
\linespread{1.3} %This is about one and half-spaced
\setlength{\parskip}{4mm plus 2mm minus 3mm} %Here we have spaces between paragraphs.
%\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}{2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}{2ex}
%%% End of layout commands.
\makeatother




\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{define}{Definition}
\newtheorem{asm}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{qn}{Question}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{clm}{Claim}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observation}



\begin{document}
\vspace{0.6cm}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\affiliation{My Uni}
%
\date{\today}
%
\begin{abstract}
\vspace{2mm}
My abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\chapter{My strange Chapter Title}
Sample text
%\section{My Failing Section Title}
Hello


\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}}
\apptocmd{\NAT@thebibliography}{\setlength\itemindent{-14pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\bibliography{/Users/Jerome/Dropbox/Bibliography/bibo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't load `epsfig` and don't do `\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}` if you are using geometry, or pdflatex

Comment: in the ams document classes, `\chapter` is defined only for books -- in `amsbook`.  it is not a logical subdivision for articles (journal or proceedings).  `\part` is provided; also `\specialsection`.  you might try one of those.

Comment: I'm not sure one should use `titlesec` with `amsart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> \chapter=undefined.
l.16 \show\chapter

? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
> \chapter=\relax.
l.18 \show\chapter
```

amsart does not define chapter (just as `article` does not).

You would have got an error message but unfortunately `natbib` defines it to silently be ignored, which is a bug in that package, really.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}            %You need this

%\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}              %Puts authors' affiliations below names
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %More math symbols
\usepackage{mathtools}                      %More math symbols
% no \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       %Insert pictures
% no \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}    %Lets you use math
\usepackage{tikz}                           %Graphs
\usepackage{setspace}                       %Allows margin and text spacing options
\usepackage{xcolor}   
\show\chapter                      %Color
\usepackage{pdfpages}                       %Lets you append pdfs
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}                   %For the bibliography
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}                 %Punctuation in bibliography
\usepackage{datenumber}                     %More formatting options for date
%\usepackage[implicit=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}                            %Lets you link items
\usepackage{tabularx}                       %Prettier tables, if we're doing them in LaTeX
\usepackage{xcolor}                         %Colors
\usepackage{needspace}                      %Insert pagebreak if not enough space
%
%Old ones
%\documentclass[a4paper,aps,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
% No!! \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox} %To generate the bibliography in aps, we need this.
\usepackage{rotating} %To use with the enviroments begin sideways etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %To prevent unexpected results when this text is copied.
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} %Das ist kein Zeichenprogramm.
%no \usepackage{graphics} 

\usepackage[citecolor= black,colorlinks=true,linkcolor = black,urlcolor  = black]{hyperref} 
%\usepackage{hypernat} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% no \usepackage{graphicx}
% no \usepackage{enumerate}
% no \usepackage{setspace} %This allows spacing
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry} %The geometry package allows the adjustment of the margin.
%\usepackage{titlesec} %This is for the spacing of section titles.
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%End of packages and libraries.
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
% no\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\@ifundefined{textcolor}{}
{%
 \definecolor{BLACK}{gray}{0}
 \definecolor{WHITE}{gray}{1}
 \definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}
 \definecolor{GREEN}{rgb}{0,1,0}
 \definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1}
 \definecolor{CYAN}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
 \definecolor{MAGENTA}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
 \definecolor{YELLOW}{cmyk}{0,0,1,0}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

% latex advancedlab ; dvips -Ppdf -t letter -G0 advancedlab

%%%New commands
\newcommand{\?}{'\-\nobreak\hspace{0pt}} %This introduces a nifty apostrophe
\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vectbr}{vecb_{r}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\col}{col}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\newcommand{\distas}[1]{\mathbin{\overset{#1}{\kern\z@\sim}}}%
\newsavebox{\mybox}\newsavebox{\mysim}
\newcommand{\distras}[1]{%
  \savebox{\mybox}{\hbox{\kern3pt$\scriptstyle#1$\kern3pt}}%
  \savebox{\mysim}{\hbox{$\sim$}}%
  \mathbin{\overset{#1}{\kern\z@\resizebox{\wd\mybox}{\ht\mysim}{$\sim$}}}%
}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%Commands for layout
\linespread{1.3} %This is about one and half-spaced
\setlength{\parskip}{4mm plus 2mm minus 3mm} %Here we have spaces between paragraphs.
%\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}{2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}{2ex}
%%% End of layout commands.
\makeatother




\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{define}{Definition}
\newtheorem{asm}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{qn}{Question}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{clm}{Claim}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observation}



\begin{document}
\vspace{0.6cm}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\affiliation{My Uni}
%
\date{\today}
%
\begin{abstract}
\vspace{2mm}
My abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle


\section{My strange Chapter Title}
Sample text
%\section{My Failing Section Title}
Hello


\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}}
\apptocmd{\NAT@thebibliography}{\setlength\itemindent{-14pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\bibliography{/Users/Jerome/Dropbox/Bibliography/bibo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha Thanks @David Carlisle but does it allow sectioning then? It did not really assign a number, either.

Comment: Oh Ok, but the section command does not work either, that is odd then no?

Comment: `\section` works, If I change `\chapter` to `\section` in your example

Comment: @Hirek Oh I get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct` If I put `titlesec` back, I removed that initially. Perhaps that package does not work with amsart out of teh box.

Comment: @Hirek I added a working version of your document

Comment: Thanks so much @David Carlisle I have accepted your answer as answering my question! I am going with barbara beeton 's advice and shall use parts instead of chapters.